# Disabling wp_tag_cloud() outputting inline CSS

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Is there a way to disable Wordpress wp_tag_cloud() from outputting inline CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to return the tag cloud as an array since every other tag parameter will still add inline font-sizing.

To return the cloud as an array you can use `<?php $tag = wp_tag_cloud('format=array' );?>`

or in a functions.php filter,

```
//tag cloud custom
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args','style_tags');
function style_tags($args) {
  $tag = wp_tag_cloud('format=array' );

 //var_dump to test output, as you can see you can style this any way you want 
 var_dump ($tag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I am trying to list custom taxonomy terms in the sidebar and wp_list_categories() does this since WP3.0 

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: Please close the question then.